# show multiple result of count

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to show the count of `idParent` in child table that where the `idParent` of the child table equals the `idContent` of the parent table.

The SQL request:

```
select count(idParent),idContent 
from content_copy_f 
where content_copy_f.idParent in (select idContent from content )
```

But it doesn't show every count of every `idParent` in every line its only showing one line with all the result.

Comment: can you paste the sample input and output?

Comment: `SELECT count(ccf.idParent) as total_idParent, ccf.idContent FROM content_copy_f ccf LEFT JOIN content c ON ccf.idParent = c.idContent` Perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:-

```
SELECT COUNT(idParent), idContent 
FROM content_copy_f
WHERE content_copy_f.idParent IN (SELECT idContent FROM content)
GROUP BY idContent;
```

hopefully this will help you.

Comment: yes that near of what i want thakns now i finich it and post it ^^

Comment: it was stupid of me not ti think of group by in the end lol :p thanks

Comment: Nothing it happens. :)